# Real-time or faux-real-time stat counter a la Teamwork.com

Tags: html, real-time, counter, stat

How is it possible to replicate or approximate the functionality that http://www.teamwork.com has on their home page, which essentially displays stats that seem to update in real time?

[image: Teamwork.com real-time stat counter]

I would like to create something very similar which counts to a series of totals, but in a realistic manner, using randomised intervals.

This would be hosted and displayed in a standard HTML5 environment and would prefer not to call from a database.

Comment: How are you storing your stats if not in a DB?

Comment: Well, my suspicion is that calling at very regular intervals from a MySQL database, for example, would be quite costly. Perhaps it's more efficient to do this from a JSON file?

Comment: Well, you either are going to do 'real' stats and query them from a data store, or make them up based on estimated rates of increase.  Depends on your requirements.

Comment: For my purposes, and apologies for not being clear about this initially, we would be making them up based on estimated rates on increase.

For example, we want somebody to land on the site and, for example, see how many people were born within the time that they've viewed the page.

Undecided on whether this count should reset upon refresh or be continuous so every new visitor sees the counter 'in progress', whichever number that may be.